# Is there a way to avoid branching/conditional-logic in this function?

Tags: c++, optimization, conditional-statements

I have this simple function in my program:

```
enum {
   TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT8 = 0,
   TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16,
   TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32,
};

// inline method
uint8_t MyTable :: GetTableIndexTypeForTableSize(uint32_t tableSize) const
{
   // Deliberately testing for strictly-less-than-255/65535 here, 
   // because 255 and 65535 are used as special sentinel values
   return (tableSize < 255) ? TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT8 
        : ((tableSize < 65535) ? TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16 : TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
}
```

In the current version of my program, I call this method whenever `tableSize` changes, and store the result in a member-variable for quick re-use, and that works fine.

However, today I am experimenting with reducing `sizeof(MyTable)`, and one way to do that is to get rid of unnecessary member-variables.  Since the cached result of the above function is always re-computable (based on the current value of the `tableSize` member-variable), I modified the code to just call `GetTableIndexTypeForTableSize(tableSize)` whenever it needs to instead.

That also works fine (and allows me reduce `sizeof(MyTable)` by 4 bytes, yay), but it leads to a measurable (~5%) decrease in performance in my performance-benchmark test -- I believe that is because the current implementation of `GetTableIndexForTableSize()` includes two branch-operations.

So my question is, is there a clever way to reimplement the above function such that it doesn't require any branching, and thus avoid the 5% slowdown?  (I presume using a lookup-table would be a 
bad idea, since I'd be replacing branch-misprediction delays with RAM-access delays, making things even slower)

Comment: When it comes to optimizations, there is generally one simple choice that has to be made: Use more memory but be more processing efficient; Or use less memory but be less processing efficient. You usually can't have both.

Comment: True, but occasionally you can; I'm hoping that this is one of those times :)

Comment: `min((31 - nlz(tableSize + 1)) >> 3, 2)` works but isn't that nice either

Comment: @harold that still might compile to a branch (or might not)

Comment: Leave such micro optimization to your compiler. On current processors, cache misses and memory access matter much more than arithmetic operations or tests. Don't forget to enable optimizations (e.g. `g++ -O2 -Wall -march=native`)

Comment: Why do you believe the following? What profiling have you done? Have you actually looked at this in a tool like `perf` or vTune and seen that you are regularly hitting branch mispredictions and that they are a bottleneck?

"I believe that is because the current implementation of GetTableIndexForTableSize() includes two branch-operations."

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is not necessarily true -- on workloads that fit in L1 cache (and even some that don't), branch mispredictions make a huge difference.

The latency of an L2 cache access is *less* than a branch mispredict on modern Intel process.

Comment: @BrennanVincent I have a benchmark that performs a large number of operations and prints out the total elapsed time, and I run the benchmark using versions of `MyTable` with and without the change described above (that's the only difference between the two versions).  The version that caches the result of this function in a local member variable consistently finishes in ~5% less time than the version that does not.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes I believe you that it is 5% slower. I'm asking how you have proven that it is because of branches specifically.

Comment: @BrennanVincent I haven't proven it, that's just my suspicion (hence "I believe" in the question text)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner right, it just seems weird to me because the branches should always be predicted correctly, no? Wouldn't tableSize have the same value many times in a row?

Comment: Typically, it would, yes; I don't have any good theory at the moment :/.   FWIW the "branchless" versions provided by you and robthebloke appear to be faster than my ternary-operator version; with those I get a 2.5% slowdown relative to the original code, rather than 5%.

Comment: Well, good; I hope it's fast enough for your needs :)

To really explain things in this level of detail (understanding a few percent here and there difference) would need a much more detailed analysis to know exactly what part of the CPU pipeline is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you choose your enum values carefully, it should be possible to bitwise or yourself to the right enum value. I doubt it will be much that quicker though.

```
#include <cstdint>
enum {
  TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT8 = 0,
  TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16 = 1,
  TABLE_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32 = 3
};

uint8_t MyTable::GetTableIndexTypeForTableSize(uint32_t tableSize) const
{
  return (tableSize >= 255) | ( (tableSize >= 65535) << 1 );
}
```

Comment: I wonder, are those >= operators likely to count as branches?

Comment: No they will not. Jumps usually only occur on if/else, for, while, switch, &&, ||, and ?: (and some other cases, e.g. tail calls)
Comparisons are no different than other CPU ops (e.g. add, sub, etc). Proof: https://godbolt.org/z/zzDZ0W  (the 2nd has a 'jb' jump, the 1st does not)

Comment: `return (tableSize >= 255) + (tableSize >= 65535);` lets you keep the old enum values.

Comment: Do any of the C or C++ standards specify that any logical expression is supposed to evaluate to 0 or 1 when assigned to a variable or returned from a function as shown here?